# I have this error when I tried getting the value from my database to datagridview

Tags: c#, database

When i tried getting the value from database to a datagrid it shows this error [image]

here's my code

```
    public void LoadRecords()
        {
            int i = 0;
            dgvProducts.Rows.Clear();          
            cm = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_Products", cn);
            cn.Open();
            dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                i++;
                dgvProducts.Rows.Add(i, dr[0].ToString(), dr[0].ToString(), dr[0].ToString(),dr[0].ToString(), dr[0].ToString());
            }
            dr.Close();
            cn.Close();
```

also here's the screenshot of the database

[image]

Comment: Do you have DataGridViewImageColumn in your data grid view? Give it a null value at least.

Comment: yes i have it in my datagridview

Answer (score 0):

The columns in your table must have an image data type in position 0, 1 or 2.  Double check the definition of your table.  Its always better to use a list of column names rather than select * .

Comment: thanks for this but another error occured saying An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.